# How is curavit being interpreted in a negative sense?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, augustinus

In his [Confessions (2.3.8)](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/augustine/conf2.shtml), Augustine writes:

> *non enim et illa quae iam de medio Babylonis fugerat, sed ibat in
> ceteris eius tardior, mater carnis meae, sicut monuit me pudicitiam,
> ita curavit quod de me a viro suo audierat, iamque pestilentiosum et
> in posterum periculosum sentiebat cohercere termino coniugalis
> affectus, si resecari ad vivum non poterat.*

The part I'm struggling with is the following:

> *ita curavit quod de me a viro suo audierat, iamque pestilentiosum et
> in posterum periculosum sentiebat cohercere termino coniugalis
> affectus*

What makes sense to me is to consider *cohercere* to be the direct object of *curavit*, with the clause *quod … sentiebat* as the direct object of *cohercere*. In that case, it would mean something like:

> … so she sought to curb, with the bonds of conjugal affection, what
> she had heard from her husband, and what she felt was an affliction
> and danger for the future

However, that's pretty much the opposite of how it's interpreted by almost all of the translations I consulted. Somehow they are interpreting this in a way such that she wasn't too worried about what her husband had said. For example, one translation has the following:

> … she **did not** seriously pay heed to what her husband had told her
> about me, and which she felt to hold danger for the future: for she
> **did not** seek to restrain my sexual drive within the limit of the marriage bond

How is this being interpreted that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As James O'Donnell notes in his [commentary](https://www.stoa.org/hippo/frames2.html), *non enim* should be taken with *ita curavit*.

I would suggest that *non enim et illa* means "For not even she," and everything from "*quae*" to "*mater carnis meae*" is a digressive elaboration about his mother, after which the thought resumes.